# Angular.js namespacing modules controllers

Tags: javascript, angularjs, namespaces, angularjs-controller, angularjs-module

I have following structure in my application directory:

```
scripts/
   modules/
     module1/
       controllers/
          MainController.js
     module2/
       controllers/
          MainController.js
   main.js
```

What I want to achieve is to put controllers in each module to its own namespace, for example:

```
module1.MainController
module2.MainController
```

So when i use in html `ng-controller="MainController"` directive it knows from which module to serve it. Also it would be good that modules can communicate with each other.

Please explain to me how I can achieve this in the best way as possible, and if it's at all possible?

---

I've found something like this:
http://jsfiddle.net/luisperezphd/j5jzsppv/ but I'm not sure if this is good solution. It uses [angular.ng-modules.js](http://rawgit.com/luisperezphd/ngModule/master/angular.ng-modules.js).

---

EDIT:
I'm trying to use Angular.js v.1.3.6. On version 1.2.x there is no problem with namespaces.

Answer (score 2):

Inject one of the modules into the other using regular dependency injection:

```
var moduleTwo = angular.module('moduleTwo', ['otherModule']);
```

This allows `moduleTwo`  to have awareness of `otherModule`.  Then you can use a service to share state between controllers.  Services are singletons (only one instance will exist), so if multiple controllers use the same service they will share that state.

Comment: Ok, I've done some research about sharing states and this is all about sharing data between controllers. What about namespaces? Still when I inject two modules which has controllers with same names, the result is taken only from the module which is injected at the end.